# How can I identify the woman interviewing Alex Honnold at the beginning of Free Solo?

Tags: rock-climbing, free-solo-climbing

The documentary Free Solo begins with footage of Honnold climbing and a voice over and cut to this interview, with the interviewer saying:

> Our next guest is a free soloing phenomenon, please welcome Alex Honnold...Here is what I don't understand. One little mistake, one little slip, and you fall and die.

[image]

The credits don't list this clip and I can't find it anywhere. Does anyone know who this is or how I could go about finding out?

Comment: Would she be [Shannon Dill](https://www.google.com/search?q=Shannon+Dill) the [movie's](https://films.nationalgeographic.com/free-solo) **producer**?

Comment: I looked her up and I really can't tell if that's her. There are no clips of her speaking that I find, and without that I'm just not sure. But thanks for the lead!

Comment: Go the publicity website and ask them?

Comment: https://films.nationalgeographic.com/free-solo the instagram, twitter or facebook is listed their of the movie producers. Also try asking national geographic.